# Data synchronization between oracle data servers

Tags: oracle, synchronization

I have a master oracle database and couple of replica servers. Replicas are read-only database. Changes made to master database are percolated to replica servers through m-views.

Problem is we are constantly adding new fields to the tables, and it requires complete m-view refreshes.

Is there any to avoid complete refresh if new columns are added to master database?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered logical standby databases?  They work really well for this situation. They stay in sync in near real time by synchronizing via redo logs. There's a bit of a learning curve involved, but I've been really happy with how well it works for our reporting database.

Read more:

[Oracle Data Guard Concepts and Administration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25608/partpage1.htm)

[Creating a Logical Standby Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25608/create_ls.htm#SBYDB00300)